# WCF possibly exceeded my response size

Tags: wcf, binding, maxreceivedmessagesize

Ok so I have finally got my WCF service running great. It has taken me some time but I have fixed just about all of my issues. The only issue I am having now is this one.

One of my data requests is fairly large, it contains a collection of about 37k. The error I am getting is as follows.

```
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing 
your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an 
underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9840000'.
```

Initially you might be thinking that its a serialization issue or that I need to change my capacity on my binding.

Here is my binding, on the client.

```
<netTcpBinding>
<binding name="MyCustomBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" 
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" 
                transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" 
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="1000000000" maxBufferSize="1000000000" 
                maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="1000000000" 
                    maxArrayLength="50000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" 
                               protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

I have changed my binding information to allow a larger capacity; however, that doesn't fix my problem. The only reason I started looking at changing the capacity for maxReceiveMessageSize is because if I throttle the results down to a collection of 1000, I have no problems. Are there any configurations other than binding that I need to worry about when it comes to large communications?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Also I have changed my timeout to like 00:10:00 on each timeout value in the binding and it didnt seem to make a difference. The response from the server is less than 5 seconds long.

**Edit 2**

Service config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
</configSections>
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings />
<client />
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior"                      
           name="MyService">
    <clear />
    <endpoint address="MyCustomObject" binding="netTcpBinding" 
              bindingConfiguration="" name="MyCustomObject" 
              contract="MyService.IContract" >
    </endpoint>

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/MyService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

**EDIT 3**

Please understand that I did not include any sensitive information about that service model, so they have been replaced with MyCustom***. Again, please read the question carefully I am successfully transferring data back and forth using this service through other endpoints without a problem. Also, like I said above I can transfer data across that endpoint if I limit the result to 1000.

**EDIT 4**

Ok let me be more clear. The client application is picking up the correct binding. The reason I know, is because when my application returns a result set of about 4500 results in a collection, gives me the following exception.

```
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has 
been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize 
property on the appropriate binding element.
```

So I increase the MaxReceiveMessageSize to the highest possible value, 2147483647. According to this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d2090703-eb60-46f4-adf7-31127338a0a0/). After I do that I can safely return my result set. Now here is the kicker, I go up to 5000 results and I get my initial exception at the top of this question.

```
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing 
your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an 
underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:59.9840000'.
```

So clearly the application is picking up the correct binding configuration otherwise it wouldn't have responded to my change in MaxReceiveMessageSize. So at this point the real question is why is it failing over such a small change.

Comment: Please post your service configuration.  It needs to also be set to an allowable size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FINALLY! Ok so this was the problem. I was exceeding the, MaxItemsInObjectGraph value on the client end. So I needed to add this behavior to the clients configuration file.

**Server config**

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior" >
      <serviceMetadata />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

**Client Config**

```
<behaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="endpointBehavior">
    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Then on the clients configuration file endpoint, I had to add that behavior.

**Client config**

```
<client>
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/RootAddress/EndpointLocation"
          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="EndpointLocation"
          behaviorConfiguration="endpointBehavior"
          contract="ServiceReference1.IInterface" name="Interface">
   <identity>
     <userPrincipalName value="" />
   </identity>
</endpoint>
</client>
```

Just to note, I had to add the behaviors section entirely to the config on the client side. As it was not generated when I use Add Service Reference. This worked flawlessly afterwards, and I was able to retrieve my 37k custom object collection.

Answer (score 0):

You are using netTcp binding on the server, but the client is configured with custom binding.

These should match, for it to work.

That is works at all is probably due to your custom binding being very close to netTcpbinding.

That is stops working at a given size that is less than 64kb, is probably due to the transfer mode. Buffered breaks down the request in chunks, as long as there is one chunk it works, when more than one the difference in the config causes it to fail.

Comment: you can;t tell what binding the client is using - its just using a config setting called MyCustomBinding

Comment: Also if it was a custom binding then all of the settings would be on the sub-binding elements not on the binding element itself

Comment: How do you specify netTcpBinding on a client configuration file?

Comment: @RichardBlewett thank you, I was a little confused about that. So far in my learning process I haven't seen where you specify that in a clients config.

Comment: I understand what you were saying now. The question has been updated. I only extracted the endpoint from the config that was in question so it didnt get its parent binding. It is using <netTcpBinding>

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your service isn't actually called `MyService` its also in a namespace which means your service config isn't actually getting used - instead a default endpoint is being wired up with default values

If you change the `name` attribute in the `service` element to the fully qualified name it should pick up the correct settings

Comment: I didn't put in the fully qualified name of my service for this question. Companies do have privacy policies that have to be followed. I will update my question with this information. Like I said in the question to begin with I am successfully transferring data back and forth just not the extremely large amounts.

Comment: But that would be the symptom of the config not being picked up under .NET 4 - you get a default endpoint for each base address and so you would have default settings for NetTcpBinding in your service which means all of the size limits would be default (64k for maxReceivedMessageSize for example)

Comment: I am sorry but my mind just isn't comprehending this solution. I have 7 other endpoints in the server config following the exact same pattern and they all work. I have also had to increase the maxReceivedMessageSize for each one because the data sets are rather large. Otherwise I will receive `The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.`

Comment: So you have the same contract on each endpoint and all operations work through the other endpoints (or at least the endpoints with the same contract)? Have you turned on tracing in the service? That will often highlight any underlying exception that triggers the issue

Comment: Well I have several other contracts, each with their own endpoint, working great. I did turn on tracing let, but it seems to just be showing me the exact same exception that I had when I was debugging.

Comment: Streaming doesn't change the limits on message sizes it just changes the way that messages are processed. Can you add an endpoint in the config for this contract over a different binding and see if  the operation with the large data works then?